# How can i replicate this View on android with xml?

Tags: android, xml, image, view, android-imageview

i'm trying to replicate a row of the linked ListView but on android.

this is my current row code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/venueLogo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/venueImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/venueName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/venueImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how i need it to look like.

[image]

How can i put an image over another one, set the title exactly in the middle of the imageView and make the other imageView round and positioned to the lower right corner?
venueImage is the background (biggest image on the view).
venueLogo is the circular little one.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example below has 3 textviews displaying exactly as you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/venueLogo"
        android:text="venue logo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="venue name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/venueName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/venueImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Geoff it almost did it, but the VenueLogo, is still behind everything and not showing

Comment: The order you have them in your xml depicts which appears on top for that. Play with the order so it's displaying right :)

Answer (score 1):

By Keeping them all inside a `RelativeLayout` then set the `venueImage` height and width to `match_parent`, create a `TextView` for the title and set it to `Center`: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to your round Image.

**Edit :**

This should be inside of your RelativeLayout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/palm"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

it should look like this

[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jowtK.jpg)

Comment: But what do i have to remove from my code apart from adding what you just said ? (my code is in the question)

Comment: all the "align ", and  " centerHorizontal"  tags then replace them with the above

Comment: doesn't seem to work, may you provide your piece of code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Frame Layout??
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html